# Having trouble getting my if/else statements to work in user defined functions

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, statements

I am currently writing a program that outputs the users hat size, jacket size, and waist size.

Hat Size = weight in pounds divided by height in inches and all that multiplied by 2.9

Jacket size (chest in inches) = height times weight divided by 288 and then adjusted by adding an 1/8 of an inch for each 10 years over the age of 30. ( Note that the adjustment only takes place after a full 10 years, no adjustment between 30 - 39, but 1/8 of an inch is added for age 40.)

Waist in inches = weight divided by 5.7 and then adjusted by adding 1/10 of an inch for each 2 years over the age of 28, full two years, so no adjustment for 29, but a 1/10th of an inch will be added if 30.

This is my code, which runs, and outputs correct values assuming the user doesn't get any of the adjustments, example age : 18.

I set up the if/else statements in my declarations below, however they don't seem to be working currently when returning.

It is a requirement that most if not all calculations done need to be preformed in a function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>


using namespace std;


double hat_size(double weight, double height);
double jacket_size(double height, double weight, double age);
double waist_size(double weight, double age);

int main()
{
    double height, weight, age;
    double Hat_size, Jacket_size, Waist_size;
    char answer;

    do
    {

        cout << "Please enter the users age: ";
        std::cin >> age;


        cout << "\n\nPlease enter users height in inches: ";
        std::cin >> height;

        cout << "\nPlease enter the users weight in pounds: ";
        std::cin >> weight;




        Hat_size = hat_size(weight, height);
        Jacket_size = jacket_size(height, weight, age);
        Waist_size = waist_size(weight, age);

        cout << "\nHat Size is: "
             << Hat_size;
        cout << "\nJacket Size is: "
            << Jacket_size
            << " inches";
        cout << "\nWaist Size is: " 
             << Waist_size
             << " inches";


        /*  

        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);

        */

        cout << "\n\nDo you want to preform another calculation? Please type Y:\n";
        std::cin >> answer;
    } while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y' || answer == 'yes' || answer == 'Yes');


    return 0;
}

double hat_size(double weight, double height)
{
    return((weight / height)*2.9);
}

double jacket_size(double height, double weight, double age)
{
    double j_size, j_age_shrink, jacket_adjustment, j_change;

    j_size = ((height * weight) / 288);
    jacket_adjustment = 1 / 8;
    j_age_shrink = (age / 10 - 3) * jacket_adjustment;
    j_change = j_size + j_age_shrink;

    if ((age / 10) >= 4)
    {
        return (j_change);
    }
    else
    {
        return (j_size);
    }
}


double waist_size(double weight, double age)
    {
        double w_size, w_age_shrink, waist_adjustment, w_change;

        w_size = (weight / 5.7);

        waist_adjustment = 1 / 10;
        w_age_shrink = ((age - 28) / 2) * waist_adjustment;
        w_change = w_size + w_age_shrink;

        if (age >= 30)
        {
            return(w_change);
        }
        else
        {
            return (w_size);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This statement will most probably leave you with zero: `jacket_adjustment = 1 / 8;` because of integer division. Use double literals instead: `jacket_adjustment = 1.0 / 8.0;`. Same for the other calculations.

Comment: does this have anything to do with css?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you that seemed to changed the values, if i change the adjustment variables to integers would that also be a way to fix it?

Comment: @Asernx No, changing to integers wouldn't work. If you need `double` math, use `double` values.